# Jquery Tooltip script easy and nice

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I search tooltip framework or script works fine as tooltip and easy for use , if you can tell me something about one tooltip works fine , perfect

I see some scripts for this but complicate for use it and all need use title for insert informations , read from title tag and i want tooltip in jquery that i can insert code into div - this div have the content , images , words , etc - and show it when i go over links , etc , i see many tooltips but no let me this and how i tell until , use title as tag

Thank´s Regards

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look here:

30 JQuery Tool tips:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/jquery-tooltip-plugin.html

or

http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/

or

http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2011/12/simple-jquery-tooltip/